# inDesign get a specific table via javascript

Tags: javascript, scripting, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I have an inDesign document with around 100 pages, most of these pages had a table. now I wanna change the content of each table.

how can select the table to change the content, for textvariables I use the label and iterate each textVariable. but if i set a label to an table, i cant find the table?

Comment: So you want to find it by the label? Just loop over all the document's tables and check if one has a matching label property.

Answer (score 2):

first part give you the access to all tables

```js
var myDoc = app.activeDocument;
var myTables = myDoc.stories.everyItem().tables.everyItem().getElements(); 

alert (myTables.length);


for (var i = 0; i < myTables.length; i++){
    myTables[i].appliedTableStyle = "Standard"; 
    myTables[i].rows[0].cells.everyItem().appliedCellStyle = "Standard_top"; 
    myTables[i].rows[-1].cells.everyItem().appliedCellStyle = "Standard_bottom"; 
}
```

the second part is a example to apply cellstyles to some rows.
So: what do you like to change in the table?